# express-validator throw exception

Tags: node.js

In my nodejs app to filter all input data I use express-validator. Something like this:

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
   req.sanitize('login').xss();
   req.sanitize('password').xss();

   //etc.
});
```

So my view is as:

```
form(action='/', method='POST')
  input(name='login', type='text')
  input(name='password', type='password')
  input(type='submit')
```

All works fine but if I omit login field for example:

```
form(action='/', method='POST')
  input(name='login', type='text')
  input(name='password', type='password')
  input(type='submit')
```

then I get exception. Why doesn't express-validator check param existing?

Comment: I had that problem too, but I've wrapped everything into a try {} catch {}. Really ugly though :|

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have the one question about that. Suppose user enter invalid login, and I need to display appropriate message in a view. Can you provide a little block of code to handle that situation?

Comment: What do you mean by invalid login?

Comment: I mean characters like '<', '$' or length > 30 for example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator) you're using it wrong.

> Validation errors
>
> You have two choices on how to get the validation errors:
>
> ```
> req.assert('email', 'required').notEmpty();
> req.assert('email', 'valid email required').isEmail();
> req.assert('password', '6 to 20 characters required').len(6, 20);
>
> var errors = req.validationErrors();
> var mappedErrors = req.validationErrors(true);
> ```

You'll need to use req.assert to validate.  req.sanitize is to sanitize input, like so:

```
req.sanitize('postparam').toBoolean();
```

Comment: Really, no one thought this answer was good enough to upvote? Dang it!  Well, thanks for accepting anyhow :)

Comment: how can use it with formidable or multiparty ? because badyParser is deprecated.